# Counting number of features within another feature using aggregate function in the QGIS Field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, point-in-polygon, aggregation, feature-count

My data: 1 polygon layer + 1 point layer
My target: Calculate the number of points and the sum of a field within each polygon using the **aggregate function in the QGIS field calculator**.

I know I can simply use the QGIS functions `"Join attributes by location (summary)"` or `"Count points in polygon"` but I'm interested in the aggregate function in the field calculator since I don´t understand exactly its meaning.

Using

```py
aggregate('hh', 'sum', "sum_pop")
```

`'hh'` - the name of the point layer
`'sum_pop'` - the name of the attribute field from the hh layer (sum of the population of a point)

I get the sum of the whole field in the attribute table, so each feature has the same value.

[image: aggregate_result_nok]

How can I change the code for the aggregate function to calculate the sum of a value based on the number of points in each polygon feature and the number of features within a polygon so I get different values for each polygon?

[image: example1]

[image: ecample2]

[image: evaluation error]

Comment: You need to add a group_by parameter. Does the point layer have a polygon_ID field that tells you which polygon each point belongs to? If so, use "polygon_ID" as the group_by parameter.

Comment: @csk The point layer does not have a field with the polygon affiliation. But using the function `Join attributes by location` this field can be generated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This expression will count the number of populated places for each country:

```py
aggregate(layer:='ne_110m_populated_places',
          aggregate:='count',
          expression:=name,
          filter:=contains(geometry(@parent), $geometry)
          )
```

you can use the same expression to get the sum, just change the aggregate to `'sum'` and the expression to the field name to summarize.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. For point counts the expression functions well (the expression parameter as string needs to be in parentheses). Although I don´t exactly understand the meaning of this expression parameter (in this case "sub expression") since I can write there whatever I want but ok. For 'sum' I just get NULL values (changing the expression parameter to "pop_sum" as the field name)  or an error (see above). pop_sum field is integer.

Comment: `aggregate(layer:= 'hh', aggregate:= 'sum', expression:= 'sum_pop_in', filter:= contains(geometry(@parent), $geometry))`

Comment: the expression should be without any quotation marks: expression:= sum_pop_in

Answer (score 8):

Since QGIS 3.16 ([see the Changelog](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#id54)) there is also a possibility using the [`overlay_contains()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#overlay-contains) function

With the following expression, it is possible to count the number of features within another feature (see example below)

```
array_length(overlay_contains('random_points_test', expression:=1))
```

[image: example]